# How to dispay data from q to textbox on VB.net

Tags: vb.net

[this is stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjVsd.png)
this is Function for SelectOne

```
  Public Function One(Id As Integer) As Object Implements IStudents.One
    Try
        Return db.SP_SelectOneStudent(Id).ToArray

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

---

```
Dim q = student.One(StudentID)
```

Comment: An object is an object, regardless of where it comes from.  You display any object in a `TextBox` in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show every field in the variable q into a TextBox:

```
...
Dim StringToShow as String = ""
For Each StringToAdd as String In q
    StringToShow &= StringToAdd & " "
Next

YourTextBox.Text = StringToShow
...
```

Comment: thw q Variable contains many statements that a variant of the array type